# Best way to include namespaces in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php

I was wondering how i should load my namespaces.

```
<?php
namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Cron;

use \MyVendor\MyModule\Model\ResourceModel\Message\Collection;

class Order 
{
    protected $_logger;
    protected $_messages;

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        Collection $_message
    ) 
    {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->_messages = $_message;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Cron\Model\Schedule $schedule) 
    {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

In this short example \MyVendor\MyModule\Model\ResourceModel\Message\Collection is loaded using "use" but \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface is loaded in the constructor.

Is there a significant difference? If yes, what is it?

Comment: No, there is no difference. If you are using same class multiple times, in that case it is recommended to use "use".

Comment: @SandipanS what does it have to do with the number of usages?

Comment: @FabianSchmengler .. i mean if I use the same class twice then it better to include the class using "use"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only readability. Technically there is no difference.

Note that you can avoid name conflicts or confusions by using one of these alternatives as well:

- Import parent namespace instead of class:

  ```
  use \MyVendor\MyModule\Model\ResourceModel\Message;

  Message\Collection $_messages
  ```
- Import class with alias:

  ```
  use \MyVendor\MyModule\Model\ResourceModel\Message\Collection as Messages;

  Messages $_messages
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much! I marked your response as the answer!